# PHP iterate through multidimensional associative array and print items

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following Array (decoded from JSON):

```
Array
(
    [playerInfo] => Array
        (
            [hint] => 
            [infoText] => Array
                (
                    [multiLineMode] => 
                    [subText1] => TLC
                    [subText2] => Christmas Pop
                    [title] => Sleigh Ride
                )

            [isPlayingInLemur] => 
            [lyrics] => 
            [mainArt] => Array
                (
                    [altText] => Album Art
                    [artType] => UrlArtSource
                    [contentType] => image/jpeg
                    [url] => https://images-na.sS500_.jpg
                )

            [mediaId] => 958d47b9:16
            [miniArt] => Array
                (
                    [altText] => Album Art
                    [artType] => UrlArtSource
                    [contentType] => image/jpeg
                    [url] => https://images-n._SS48_.jpg
                )

            [miniInfoText] => Array
                (
                    [multiLineMode] => 
                    [subText1] => TLC
                    [subText2] => Prime Music
                    [title] => Sleigh Ride
                )

            [playbackSource] => 
            [playingInLemurId] => 
            [progress] => Array
                (
                    [allowScrubbing] => 1
                    [locationInfo] => 
                    [mediaLength] => 223
                    [mediaProgress] => 80
                    [showTiming] => 1
                    [visible] => 1
                )

            [provider] => Array
                (
                    [artOverlay] => PRIME_SASH
                    [fallbackMainArt] => Array
                        (
                            [altText] => 
                            [artType] => IconArtSource
                            [iconId] => music-no-art
                            [iconStyles] => 
                        )

                    [providerLogo] => Array
                        (
                            [altText] => Amazon Music
                            [artType] => IconArtSource
                            [iconId] => amazon-music
                            [iconStyles] => 
                        )

                    [providerName] => Prime Music
                )

            [queueId] => 958d47
            [state] => PAUSED
            [template] => 
            [transport] => Array
                (
                    [layoutType] => MusicTransportLayout
                    [lyrics] => HIDDEN
                    [next] => ENABLED
                    [playPause] => ENABLED
                    [previous] => ENABLED
                    [repeat] => ENABLED
                    [shuffle] => ENABLED
                )

            [volume] => Array
                (
                    [muted] => 
                    [volume] => 40
                )

        )

)
```

I have the following foreach loop which prints every item (4) in the infoText array.

```
<?php
    foreach ($player['playerInfo']['infoText'] as $music) {
        echo $music;
    }
?>
```

But I want to be able to print only the [title] in infoText array, [state] in the playerInfo parent array, and [volume] in the volume array. Is there an elegant way to do this? Also, since I'm using foreach, I only get the value of the pair, but I also need the key. That way I can print the specific items I need.

Comment: `<?php echo 'STATE: '.$data['playerInfo']['state'].' <br /> Title: '.$data['playerInfo']['infoText']['title']; ?>`

Comment: "since I'm using foreach, I only get the value of the pair, but I also need the key." `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`

Comment: @Jhecht what should the foreach be? thanks for your reply

Comment: @Greg Why do you need a foreach loop if you can access the elements directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try a recursion function so you don't have to keep track of all those keys.  I shortened your array for this example but it should work for you regardless of dimensions.  Just provide the key to get the value in an array for the $searchterms argument.

```
function array_recursion(array $myarray, array $searchterms)
{
        foreach ($myarray as $key => $value)
        {
                if (is_array($value)) array_recursion($value, $searchterms);
                else if (in_array($key, $searchterms)) print $key . ": " . $value . "\n";

        }
}

$myarray = Array(
        'playerInfo' => Array(
                'hint' => '',
                'infoText' => Array(
                        'multiLineMode' => '',
                        'subText1' => 'TLC',
                        'subText2' => 'Christmas Pop',
                        'title' => 'Sleigh Ride'
                ),
                'state' => 'PAUSED',
                'volume' => Array(
                        'muted' => '',
                        'volume' => 40
                        )
        )
);

array_recursion($myarray, Array('state', 'title', 'volume'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as though 'infoText' is an array containing title, you would do it like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($player as $key => $music) {
    echo $music['infoText']['title'];
}
```

And then you can also use `$key` to get the array key for the current iteration.

Comment: This prints out the first character in each iteration.

Comment: I do not think you need recursion for this. Recursion is appropriate when you have nested data trees with an unknown depth level. In this case, it appears that the key structure follows a pretty specific schema which can be anticipated, making recursion somewhat redundant.